# preg_match_all overlapping variants <a><b><c><d> to produce <a><b>, <b><c>, <c><d>

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i want to enclose any word between two start tags into `<span>anyword</span>`.

for example given this

```
<li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">Leagues<span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left"><span>
```

between `<li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">` there is no word

between `<a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">Leagues<span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left">` there is a word "Leagues"

So I want to enclose Leagues with `<span>Leagues</span>` and replace it to 
`<a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown"><span>Leagues</span><span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left">`

I am using the expression

```
preg_match_all('~<\w+[^>]*>([^><]*)<\w+[^>]*>~',$html,$matches);
```

where

```
$html =<<<'EOD'
<li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">Leagues<span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left"><span>
EOD;
```

this returns

```
array(
0   =>  <li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">
1   =>  <span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left"><span>
)
```

instead of

```
array(
0   =>  <li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">
1 => <a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">Leagues<span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left">
1   =>  <span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left"><span>
)
```

Please I want someone to help me.

Comment: finally got the solution. (?=(<\w+[^>]*>([^><]*)<\w+[^>]*>))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, you need to use `lookaheads`.
It matches a regex and then discards it for subsequent matching. 
So, tweaking your regex a little bit -

```
(<\w+[^>]*>)([^><]+)(?=<\w+[^>]*>)
^          ^      ^ ^^^          ^ Additions
```

Basically, I've added a new capturing group(used in replace), added a `+` instead of `*` and a lookahead - `(?=...)`.
So, if there is a text of the form - `<tag1>content1<tag2>content2<tag3>...`

This will match `<tag1>content1<tag2>`(The capturing group will get the `content1` string). Since, `<tag2>` is matched in the positive lookahead, the next matching will start from `<tag2>` rather than `content2`.

Here is an example of what you want to achieve -

```
$html =<<<EOD
<li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">Leagues<span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left">Leagues2<span>
EOD;

$resp = preg_replace(
    "~(<\w+[^>]*>)([^><]+)(?=<\w+[^>]*>)~",
    "$1<span>$2</span>",
    $html
);

var_dump($html);
var_dump($resp);
```

This outputs -

```
// Original String -
<li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown">Leagues<span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left">Leagues2<span>

// Replaced string 
<li class="nav__league"><a href="/leagues" class="nav__link nav__dropdown"><span>Leagues</span><span class="nav__link__helper nav__link__helper--left"><span>Leagues2</span><span>
```

Comment: your method works, i later found another way of solving this problem by using (?=(<\w+[^>]*>([^><]*)<\w+[^>]*>)) , which will match all overlapping patterns then a further processing will allow one to enclose between words into <span></span>. thanks